# Corona Scroll with buttons and/or images = Scrolling + Clicking

Tags: scrollview, coronasdk, addeventlistener

How can buttons or images inside a scrollview work when clicked, 
but if they are moved(scrolled) still keep the scrolling functionality?

I read about returning true from event handling function. http://developer.anscamobile.com/content/events-and-listeners#Touch_Events

But this appears to work only for buttons on top of buttons (tap/click). Anyways tried returning true after event handler but did not help.

I can detect if button was moved, but don't know if that can activate/propagate to scroll.

Here's a simpler version of the code

```
-- ScrollView listener
local function scrollListener( event )
    local phase = event.phase
    local direction = event.direction
    return true
end

-- Create the widget
local scrollView = widget.newScrollView
{
    ...
    listener = scrollListener
}

-- Create a image and insert it into the scroll view
local background = display.newImageRect( "assets/scrollimage.png", 768, 1024 )

-- Image/Button Listener
function blaBla( event )

    if event.phase == "ended" then
       -- do something on click
    elseif event.phase == "moved" then
        -- can't do anything to propagate this event to the scroll
    end

    return true
end

background:addEventListener( "touch", blaBla )

scrollView:insert( background )
```

Answer (score 0):

returning true from the touch listener inhibits propagation of the event to other listeners. you should not return true.

you could also just call the scroll listener from the touch listener.